# SQLAlchemy - TypeError: Boolean value of this clause is not defined

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm creating a python application that has a database with results from different soccer matches.

I want the model to set its `result` field based on the values of the `home_score` and `away_score` fields.

I've worked a lot with Django - but not this time as its going to be a simple terminal application. If I was I would have sub-classed the `save` method with some of the code in the `result` method below.

Being somewhat new to SQLAlchemy I assumed that the `@hybrid_property` decorator was a good proxy for what I was trying to achieve.

However, when I run my unittests for this model it fails on the following line
`elif self.home_score > self.away_score:`

with the following error:

`TypeError: Boolean value of this clause is not defined`

I've included the model below, does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
class Match(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'matches'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = Column(Date, nullable=False)
    home_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('teams.id'))
    home = relationship(
        "Team", back_populates='home_matches', foreign_keys=[home_id]
    )
    away_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('teams.id'))
    away = relationship(
        "Team", back_populates='away_matches', foreign_keys=[away_id]
    )
    home_score = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    away_score = Column(Integer, nullable=False)


    @hybrid_property
    def result(self):
        """ Set the match result, based on the team scores """
        if self.home_score == self.away_score:
            return 'draw'
        elif self.home_score > self.away_score:
            return 'home'
        elif self.home_score < self.away_score:
            return 'away'
```

Comment: Does the tests for the rest of the conditionals also fail?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea of a hybrid property is to produce equivalent SQL, when used in query context. For some simple expressions the same code works for both, but if not you must define the expression separately. In this case you can replace your Python with an SQL `CASE` expression:

```
from sqlalchemy import case

...

@hybrid_property
def result(self):
    """ Set the match result, based on the team scores """
    if self.home_score == self.away_score:
        return 'draw'
    elif self.home_score > self.away_score:
        return 'home'
    elif self.home_score < self.away_score:
        return 'away'

@result.expression
def result(cls):
    """ Set the match result, based on the team scores """
    return case([(cls.home_score == cls.away_score, 'draw'),
                 (cls.home_score > cls.away_score, 'home')],
                else_='away')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Unfortunately when I try this code it fails with a `AttributeError: can't set attribute` error. (Though its of course possible that my own code is the problem here, I will look into it!)

Comment: Cannot reproduce, so I'm inclined to say that the error is elsewhere.

Comment: @Jasper did you get this to work - I'm facing the same issue now with AttributeError